# Issue with data binding in parent and child relationship,

Tags: angular, typescript

I am Beginner to angular 6 and currently facing an problem with data binding. I have created a test project which is showing a heading with data binding with parent and child relationship, but its not working...Any one can please help me with this?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1> //need to print child components title variable 
                       //inside parent template
    <childcomponent>Child component title is: {{title}}</childcomponent>
    `
    //and also inside the child componets selector
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Parent component';
}
```

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<p>child component works</p> `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  title = 'Child component';
}
```

Comment: post your child component code

Comment: child component added.

Comment: Should your `ChildComponent` selector be `childcomponent` and not `app-root`? The component selector is what you use in the parent template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you are trying to achieve is, passing data from child component to parent component. Below solution is done with the help of "Local variable".

### Parent Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>{{child.title}}</h1>
    <childcomponent #child></childcomponent>
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Parent component';
}
```

---

### Child Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'childcomponent',
  template: `<p>Child component title is: {{title}}</p> `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  title = 'Child component';
}
```

---

So, the output will be as follows:

[image: Angular Parent Child Component Interaction]

You can also achieve the same result with 2 more methods:
1. Parent listening to child component event.
2. Parent uses @ViewChild to get reference to the child component.

Comment: NO....I need to print the child value inside <childcomponent> selector and outside of parentCOmponent

Comment: @ChristianDeLorence Can you give an output sample example ?

Comment: Child component 

Child component title is:Child component

Answer (score 1):

I really do not understand the purpose here, you can just display the title without using a child component directly.

If you still want to pass to your child component, should go for @input EventEmitter mechanism to pass data from your parent to child

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3cse5?file=src/app/child.component.ts)**